# failed heath checks on target groups because the url is parsing and symlinks

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, symlink, url-parsing

Ubuntu Server has been configured with Apache.
We are trying to implement autoscaling using Application Load Balancer but the Target Group is failing health checks (*Autoscaling groups are showing instances as healthy).
Health Check failed with 404 error is thrown by the Target Group(The Load Balancer is not able to locate the webpage(Index.html/index.php))
Virtual Document Root is /var/www/html/%-1.0.%-1/%-2+ and the default document root /var/www/html has no webpages.
The url gets parsed and the document root is built from the url.
So abc.example.com equates to /var/www/html/example.com/secure, which is a symbolic link to another directory where the application code is hit.

Comment: it's not clear from your question exactly where the health check is looking, but where ever you have it pointed at, that URL has to return a 200.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I dont know what exact path is to be set for the health check monitor. I had  kept it at as default but it is showing the same error. For  testing purpose, I tried configuring Windows Server with IIS and the health check did not fail.

Comment: if you are sending the health check to the correct host then the 404 will be logged in one of the apache logs.  Look in the log and then use the path to configure apache.  This answer from serverfault might be useful to you https://serverfault.com/questions/557724/how-configure-apache-httpd-to-answer-http-200-with-empty-body-on-specific-url

Comment: I am also getting an error in the log which says:  "\x16\x03\x01" 400 226

Comment: Solved this problem by creating a separate target group that listens at port 80 and created a rule in load balancers listeners tab that forwards traffic to it